# How to use glColor when I used glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

Tags: opengl

how to use glColor when I used glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

Normally under glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY); glColorPointer is used.
At times I want to colour everything with single colour temporarily.

In that sense, what I felt using glColor3f is good.
But while I am using it is working sometimes and not working some times.

Can any body help me how to use glColor in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```